# I am trying to search my java multidimensional array from top left to bottom right going in a vertical pattern. What is wrong with the code I have?

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array, traversal

I am trying to search my multidimensional array that is a 6x8 grid from top left to bottom right in a vertical pattern for a word, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
      public static String findTopToBottom (char[][]board, String word) {
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i <= board[i].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= board.length; j++) {
                boolean found = true;

                for (int k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
                    if ((i + k > board[j].length) || (letters[k] != board[j][i+k])) {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found) {
                    return "String " + word + " found in row=" + i + " col=" +j;
                }
            }
        }
        return "String " + word + " not found";
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe how it's wrong?

Comment: It's not working at all and I'm getting an index out of bounds error.

Comment: In your second loop, `board.length` probably isn't what you want, since it's a 2D array.

Comment: @JesseJ no, that's wrong, since he's intentionally trying to go through the array in an unusual order, I think: down each column first, instead of across each row first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((i + k > board[j].length) || (letters[k] != board[j][i+k])) {
```

will throw an out-of-bounds exception if `i + k` is equal to `board[j].length`, since indexes only go from 0 to `.length - 1`.  Use `>=` instead of `>`.

For the same reason, `<=` in the following need to be changed to `<`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= board[i].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= board.length; j++) {
```

since the maximum possible index will be `.length - 1`.

And this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= board[i].length; i++) {
```

just looks wrong, even after changing `<=` to `<`.  The `i` index is supposed be the index of a column in the array, but when you say `board[i].length` you are treating `i` as a row index.  This will not cause a problem for a 6x8 array, but it will for an 8x6 array, say, because you want `i` to go from 0 to 7, but when `i=6`, `board[6].length` will be out of bounds.  If you're certain that all of the rows are the same length, you should change this to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < board[0].length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution :

```
public static String findTopToBottom(char[][] board, String word) {
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();

    if (letters.length <= board.length) {
        int lettersIndex = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {

            // scan horizontally
            for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++) {
                if (board[r][c] == letters[0]) {
                    // found first letter now scan vertically
                    lettersIndex++;

                    // now go down
                    for (int r1 = r+1; r1 < board.length; r1++) {
                        if (c < board[r1].length && board[r1][c] == letters[lettersIndex]) {
                            lettersIndex++;

                            if (lettersIndex == letters.length) {
                                return "String " + word + " found in row=" + r + " col=" + c;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // no break it
                            lettersIndex = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }// found first
            }
        }
    }

    return "String " + word + " not found";
}
```

It can work in any kind of array.

So the steps of my algorithm are :

1. Scan each row horizontally
2. If you find the first letter of the **word** scan vertical

   1. If during vertical scanning equality fails stop and continue last horizontal scan.
   2. If you find continusly equal all letters of the **word** return success.